# VirtueMart Search Error

Tags: mysql, joomla, virtuemart

So I am after updating Virtuemart and I am getting this error when I look for a particular product on a clients site:

> vmError: exeSortSearchListQuery Unknown column 'p.product_sku' in 'where clause'

```
SQL=SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.`virtuemart_product_id` 
FROM `tqmux_virtuemart_products` as p 
INNER JOIN `tqmux_virtuemart_products_en_gb` as l 
  using (`virtuemart_product_id`) 
LEFT JOIN `tqmux_virtuemart_product_manufacturers` 
   ON p.`virtuemart_product_id` = `tqmux_virtuemart_product_manufacturers`.`virtuemart_product_id` 
WHERE ((`l`.product_name LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `product_sku` LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `l`.`slug` LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `l`.product_s_desc LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `l`.`metadesc` LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `p.product_sku` LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `c.category_name` LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `c.category_description` LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `m.mf_name` LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `p.product_name` LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR `p.product_s_desc` LIKE "%anya%") 
   AND `tqmux_virtuemart_product_manufacturers`.`virtuemart_manufacturer_id` = 1    
   AND p.`virtuemart_vendor_id` = "1" ) 
 group by p.`virtuemart_product_id` 
 ORDER BY p.`created_on` DESC, `virtuemart_product_id` DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 20
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what table tqmux_virtuemart_products has in it (DDL)?  The error is implying column product_Sku doesn't exist in that table.  Additionally why do you have a `product_Sku` and `p.product_Sku` in the where?  What table is the first product_Sku to be sourced from?  Lastly table aliases `p`,`l` seem to exist where are `c`,`m` coming from?

Comment: I don't build the queries myself, VM does it themselves. I'll attached the image of the table to the question above.

Comment: @xQbert do you see what the problem is if you don't mind me asking? I have been trying for wks and getting no where.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this the first go...`p.product_sku` should be `p`.`product_SKU backticks around each

Answer (score 0):

I generally only use backtic's only when I have to.  Such as on spaces in column names or reserved word column names, otherwise leave them out for readability and so you do not encounter these types of errors.

```
`p.product_sku` 

 should be

`p`.`product_sku`
```

so...

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.virtuemart_product_id
FROM tqmux_virtuemart_products as p 
INNER JOIN tqmux_virtuemart_products_en_gb as l 
  using (virtuemart_product_id) 
LEFT JOIN tqmux_virtuemart_product_manufacturers tvpm
   ON p.virtuemart_product_id = tvpm.virtuemart_product_id
WHERE ((l.product_name LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR product_sku LIKE "%anya%"   
        OR l.slug LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR l`.product_s_desc LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR l`.`metadesc LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR p.product_sku LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR c.category_name LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR c.category_description LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR m.mf_name LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR p.product_name LIKE "%anya%" 
        OR p.product_s_desc LIKE "%anya%") 
   AND tvpm.virtuemart_manufacturer_id = 1    
   AND p.virtuemart_vendor_id = "1" ) 
 group by p.virtuemart_product_id 
 ORDER BY p.created_on DESC, virtuemart_product_id DESC
```

I'd also like to know why

```
            OR p.product_sku LIKE "%anya%" 
and         OR product_sku LIKE "%anya%"
```

are both in the query.  they appear to do the same thing.

Comment: Ok cool. Where can I access the file to alter it? I never altered that piece of code. All I did recently was updated virtuemart, updated the db, etc and that was it.

Comment: getting out of my expertise: http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=115951.0 shows or perhaps: https://virtuemart-manager.com/useful-articles/tips-tricks/what-are-custom-sqls-and-how-to-manage-virtuemart-data-using-them/  I've not used virtuemart myself; but lookign at the SQL the missing, or improperly placed ticks are what's causing the issue.  can you remove and re-add the elements that generate this SQL?  Simply put: `p.product_name` isn't a column name it's a table & column Name.  We need to eliminate the back ticks or ensure they get put around each string not the dot.